# Best method to keep lookup file value fresh

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Say, I have to monitor users' activities from 3 specific departments: Science, History, and Math.

The goal is to send an alert if any of the users in any of those departments download a file from site XYZ.

Currently, I have a lookup file for all the users from those three departments.

```
users
----------------------
user1@organization.edu
user2@organization.edu
user3@organization.edu
user4@organization.edu
user5@organization.edu
```

One problem: users can join, leave, or transfer to another department anytime.

Fortunately, those activities (join and leave) are tracked and they are Splunk-able.

```
index=directory status=*
-----------------------------------------------
{
"username":"user1@organization.edu",
"department":"Science",
"status":"added"
}
{
"username":"user1@organization.edu",
"department":"Science",
"status":"removed"
}
{
"username":"user2@organization.edu",
"department":"History",
"status":"added"
}
{
"username":"user3@organization.edu",
"department":"Math",
"status":"added"
}
{
"username":"MRROBOT@organization.edu",
"department":"Math",
"status":"added"
}
```

In this example, assuming I forgot to update the lookup file, I won't get an alert when MRROBOT@organization.edu downloads a file, and at the same time, I will still get an alert when user1@organization.edu downloads a file.

One solution that I could think of is to update the lookup manually via using inputlookup and outputlook method like:

```
inputlookup users.csv | users!=user1@organization.edu | outputlookup users.csv
```

But, I don't think this is an efficient method, especially there's high likely I might miss a user or two.

Is there a better way to keep the lookup file up-to-date? I googled around, and one suggestion is to use a cronjob CURL to update the list. But, I was wondering if there's a simpler or better alternative than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a search that should automate the maintenance of the lookup file using the activity events in Splunk.

```
`comment("Read in the lookup file.  Force them to have old timestamps")`
| inputlookup users.csv | eval _time=1, status="added"
`comment("Add in activity events")`
| append [ search index=foo ]
`comment("Keep only the most recent record for each user")`
| stats latest(_time) as _time, latest(status) as status by username
`comment("Throw out users with status of 'removed'")`
| where NOT status="removed"
`comment("Save the new lookup")`
| table username
| outputlookup users.csv
```

After the `append` command, you should have a list that looks like this:

```
user1@organization.edu added
user2@organization.edu added
user3@organization.edu added
user4@organization.edu added
user5@organization.edu added
user1@organization.edu added
user1@organization.edu removed
user2@organization.edu added
user3@organization.edu added
MRROBOT@organization.edu added
```

The `stats` command will reduce it to:

```
user4@organization.edu added
user5@organization.edu added
user1@organization.edu removed
user2@organization.edu added
user3@organization.edu added
MRROBOT@organization.edu added
```

with the `where` command further reducing it to:

```
user4@organization.edu added
user5@organization.edu added
user2@organization.edu added
user3@organization.edu added
MRROBOT@organization.edu added
```

Comment: What a brilliant workaround! So, basically, all I need to do is to run this search twice a day or once a day every morning, right?

Comment: Run as often as necessary to keep the lookup file as current as you need it to be.